# Keep handler and service alive while waiting for response from separate thread?

Tags: android, wakelock

I'm using a repeating alarm to trigger a BroadcastReceiver (`OnAlarmReceiver`) which in turn calls `WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, PmNotificationService.class);`

The `doWakefulWork` method is displayed below

```
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    // Load auth information from server
    Authentication.loadAuthenticationInformation(this);

    if (hasAuthInformation()) {
        getRequestParameters().execute(getRequestHandler());
    }
}
```

The `getRequestParameters().execute(getRequestHandler());` line creates an `AjaxRequest` object, along with a `RequestHandler` object, and the idea was that once the Ajax request is completed, it would send the information back to the `RequestHandler`.

In this case the handler is the `PmNotificationService` class (which extends `WakefulIntentService`).

The problem, and thus the basis of my question is the following message:

> 05-12 12:09:08.139: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Stopping service: com.sofurry/.services.PmNotificationService
>
> 05-12 12:09:08.558: WARN/MessageQueue(333): Handler{4393e118} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>
> 05-12 12:09:08.558: WARN/MessageQueue(333): java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler{4393e118} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
>
> ...

Obviously the service stops running as soon as it has sent off the request, as that request runs in another thread, and as a result hereof the Handler is dead.

So my question is: Can I keep the service and thus the handler alive until I get a response (ie. wait for that other thread)? I would prefer it if I could, as the AjaxRequest object is maintained by someone else, and is used throughout the entire application.

**Update**

I obviously missed one *very* important point, namely that the `WakefulIntentService` inherits from `IntentService` instead of `Service` which means it will stop itself after it has done its work. I have currently solved it by changing the `doWakefulWork` method slightly. Here's the new one:

```
@Override
protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
    RequestThread thread = null;

    // Load auth information from server
    Authentication.loadAuthenticationInformation(this);

    if (hasAuthInformation()) {
        thread = getRequestParameters().execute(getRequestHandler());

        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if using `thread.join()` is the best way to manage this, so I'll leave the question unanswered for a few days, before I post an answer, just in case someone has a better solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntentService already uses a background thread for onHandleIntent().
Hence, do not use AsyncTask -- just execute your code in onHandleIntent().

Check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/YDrGmFDFUeU